# Why won't Django acknowledge my class variable?

Tags: python, django

I've defined the following form class in a Django project (Django 1.11, Python 3.5), but when I execute `python3 manage.py runserver`, I receive a

```
 NameError: name 'month_names' is not defined
```

---

```
class MonthForm(forms.Form):
    month_names = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
        ]
    MONTH_CHOICES = [(i + 1, month_names[i]) for i in range(len(month_names))]
    month = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MONTH_CHOICES, label='Month',
                              widget=forms.Select())
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. I've noticed that if I move the initial `month_names` assignment outside of the class definition, then it works. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Form` [*metaclass*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) - [`DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/550cb3a365dee4edfdd1563224d5304de2a57fda/django/forms/forms.py#L26) -  does not allow you to create (and by extension, bind) arbitrary objects that are not fields (i.e. instance of `django.forms.fields.Field`) on the class.

You'll have to declare such *arbitrary* objects outside the `Form` subclass.

Comment: Okay, I figured it was something like that. To be honest, I'm still relatively new with Python. Thanks a lot.